# regex. Любой символ включая перенос строки

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Есть у меня некоторый запрос. Предположим `/s <text>`. Надо, чтобы моя регулярка могла учитывать любой символ. Я бы использовал `^/s (.*)`, но эта штука не видит перенос строки и ломается на:

```
/s
1 2 3
A B C
```

Может быть, дело в том, что использую я это через re.match() из python3.
Код:

```
re_result = re.match('^/s (.*)', text)
```

Вопрос: как мне сделать то, что мне нужно?

Comment: попробуйте так: `re.match('^/s (.*)', text, flags=re.M | re.S)`

Comment: @MaxU, не хочешь написать в ответ? Да, это помогло

Answer (score 5, accepted):

При использовании [`re.match`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match) поиск совпадения осуществляется только в начале строки, поэтому `^` является лишним.

Символы перевода строки `.` по умолчанию не находит, эту функциональность надо "включить" с помощью опции [`re.S` / `re.DOTALL`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.S).

Кроме того, после `s` в оригинальной строке нет пробела, есть перевод строки, поэтому лучше использовать шаблон `\s`, находящий любой пробельный символ.

См. [пример кода](https://ideone.com/xjHBsE):

```
import re
text = '''/s
1 2 3
A B C'''
re_result = re.match('/s\s(.*)', text, re.S)
if re_result:
    print("Совпадение найдено! Полное совпадение:")
    print(re_result.group())
    print("Значение первой группы:")
    print(re_result.group(1))
```

Вывод:

```
Совпадение найдено! Полное совпадение:
/s
1 2 3
A B C
Значение первой группы:
1 2 3
A B C
```