# Почему символ точки в regex не захватывает переносы строки?

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Нередко в материалах по `regex` говорят, что спецсимвол точка `.` означает любой символ. Но это не так, точка обозначает [любой символ кроме переноса строки](http://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave.Marshall/Internet/NEWS/regexp.html).

Я получил из-за этого ошибку и вообще меня такой расклад удивил.

Допустим, я хочу сделать захват такого текста:

```
Шла Саша по шоссе
и сосала


сушку
```

Я бы сделал что-то подобное: `\A.*\Z`, вот только выясняется, что это не работает. Зато представленный выше текст можно захватить при помощи указания символов, которые *не* должны встречаться. Вот так например: `\A[^%]*\Z`

У меня два вопроса:

1. Почему точка не обозначает перенос строки *(в чём был смысл такого решения)*?
2. Как мне справиться с ситуацией, когда я хочу сделать захват вообще всего, что угодно, переносов строки в том числе?

**Важное примечание: я знаю про существование [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/711476/regex-%D0%9B%D1%8E%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB-%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8) вопроса. Но во-первых я хочу понять, почему вообще так исторически сложилось, что точка не захватывает перенос строки. А во-вторых меня интересует решение проблемы в контексте `java`.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы точка соответствовала любому символу, включая перенос строки, необходимо включить режим [`Pattern.DOTALL`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL).

Например, этот код захватит целиком весь текст, вместе с переносами строк:

```java
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*", Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

Этот режим можно включить и другим способом, добавить флаг `?s` непосредственно в регулярное выражение.

Например, для многострочного текста здесь мы получим true:

```java
System.out.println(text.matches("(?s).*"));
```

Какие еще бывают флаги можно посмотреть в официальном [туториале](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/pattern.html).

---

[Исторически](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) так сложилось из-за того, что первые инструменты, которые использовали регулярные выражения, обрабатывали тексты построчно. Поэтому, предполагалось, что переноса строки в тексте быть не должно.

Концепт регулярных выражений [появился](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) в 1950-х годах. Регулярки широко использовались вместе с юниксовыми текстовыми утилитами. Если вам приходилось иметь дело с командной строкой linux, то вы могли видеть, как работать с текстом с помощью `grep`, `sed`, `awk` и `perl`: большинство команд применяются к тексту строчка за строчкой.